# Align li to the left IE8

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Hello I am trying to align LI items to the left.

Here is my code. I have tried several solutions but nothing seems to work.

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    list-style:none;padding:0
}
```

**HTML:**

```
    <table  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">   
     <tr>
      <td>
       <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
      </ul>     
      </td>  
    </tr>   
   </table>
```

With Chrome thery are correctly aligned to the left .
Ho could I make it alligne in IE 8 as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
ul{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none}
```

This works.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use reset css code:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```